# Python change data into sequence

Tags: python, url

The "idata" I pulled from this URL needs to be turned into a sequence, how do i turn it into a sequence

```
import urllib, csv

URL = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%s&f=sl1vt1&e=.csv"
symbols = ('GGP', 'JPM', 'AIG', 'AMZN','GGP', 'JPM', 'AIG', 'AMZN')
#symbols = ('GGP',)

def fetch_quote(symbols):
    url = URL % '+'.join(symbols)
    fp = urllib.urlopen(url)
    try:
        data = fp.read()
    finally:
        fp.close()
    return data # <======== Return

idata = fetch_quote(symbols)
print idata
```

[Python URL download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637553/python-url-download)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "a sequence"? You could turn it into a dictionary as follows. Just place this code after you produce `idata`.

```
stocks = {}
for line in idata.split("\r\n"):
    if line == '':
        continue

    stock, price, volume, stime = line.split(',')
    stock = stock[1:-1]
    price = float(price)
    volume = int(volume)
    stime = stime[1:-1]

    stocks[stock] = (price, volume, stime)
```

If you want to be a bit more robust, you can use the `csv` module (add `import csv` to the top of your code) then use

```
reader = csv.reader(idata.split("\r\n"))

stocks = {}
for line in reader:
    if line == '':
        continue

    stock, price, volume, stime = line
    price = float(price)
    volume = int(volume)

    stocks[stock] = (price, volume, stime)
```

For inserting into a database, the following may work

```
reader = csv.reader(idata.split("\r\n"))

stocks = []
for line in reader:
    if line == '':
        continue

    stock, price, volume, stime = line
    price = float(price)
    volume = int(volume)

    stocks.append((stock, price, volume, stime))

csr.executemany('INSERT INTO test.prices VALUES (?,?,?,?)', stocks)
```

This of course assumes your columns are in the same order as the elements of the array.

Comment: Thanks,  I am tring to Insert the data into Sqlite using 

    csr.executemany('INSERT INTO test.prices VALUES (?,?,?,?)', idata)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: The second parameter to executemany must be a sequence.

for row in idata:
 csr.execute('INSERT INTO test.prices VALUES (?,?,?,?)', idata)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 4 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Comment: thanks, for our help......

    stock, price, volume, stime = line
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Comment: thanks, used method 1....changed to list.....
I would like to try method 3.... if you figure out error.....

Answer (score 1):

I would guess based on the URL that you are downloading data in CSV format. As such, you probably want to parse it with a [CSV reader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html).

Comment: "for row in idata:
     print row 
 
gives me weird data

Comment: Define weird? What does the data look like when you just download it in a browser?

Comment: the data goes one character straight down.