# Remove/Replace Error from Tuple in python

Tags: python, tuples

I have string of tuples

```
LL =  [ ("text1",2,3,N/A), ("text2",N/A,5,6),("text3",N/A,5,N/A) ]
```

I need

```
LL =  [ ("text1",2,3,-1), ("text2",-1,5,6), ("text2",-1,5,-1) ]
```

So simply remove N/A replace with -1. Do I need to read all lines? 
Data download shows N/A, its not a variable.

LL is string

Using `("text2",N/A,5,6)`.
Running python type on `[0]` is 'str'.
Running python type on `[1]` , i get no output.

If I split the line above  as a, b,c,d, 
Since I want number not a N/A, is there a way to say if not number replace with a number (-1). WHILE SPLITTING each line. Or, if error replace with -1.

Here is another link with the same problem, notice [1] has a N/A. 
http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GS&f=sb6vt1&e=.csv

After struggling with data download with ill tempered CSV fields. How could use try/Except format.

```
try: 
   IF XXX or YYY or ZZZ or AAA == 'N/A',
   (dont process data...skip to except and pass)
except:
   pass
```

Comment: What is `N/A`? Do you mean `"N/A"`?

Comment: Is `N/A` a string?  What you have now is not valid Python syntax unless you are dividing a value `N` by `A`.

Comment: No, its N/A not text 'N/A'. Data download shows N/A> ;-(

Comment: There's no `N/A`, unless you define two variables `N` and `A` as numbers (or something overloading `__div__` in a weird way).

Comment: What is N/A? In the form you wrote it, name is not defined.

Comment: What does 'data download' mean?

Comment: I herewith nominate this question for the `confusion-of-idea` tag.

Comment: LL comes as a dataset, which is downloaded, I dont create it.

Comment: Please show output of "print type(LL[0][3])", after that you can use list comprehensions for create list with new tuples.

Comment: @oxyum, i create the example, The real set has to many rows, and error isnt in every line.

Comment: show output of ANY element that showed as "N/A", or you can replace all elements where "type not in (str, integer)" with -1?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `None` instead of `N/A`?

Comment: It's a CSV file, so treat it like one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source you're downloading from is a csv file, not some weird python typle thing. You can handle CSVs more directly and easily by using the [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) instead of you're hacked together solution.

```
import csv, urllib
rawStockInfo = csv.reader(urllib.urlopen('http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GS+AAPL+MSFT+AMZN&f=sb6vt1&e=.csv'))
stocks = [] #list for our cleaned up version
for stock in rawStockInfo:
    print stock
    #this replaces the string "N/A" with the int -1
    stockClean = [-1 if x == 'N/A' else x for x in stock]
    stocks.append(stockClean)
print stocks
```

Note that you may want to change that list expression into another loop over the cells in `stock`... This would try to convert any strings to integers, and also replace 'N/A' with -1.

```
stockClean = []
for cell in stock:
    try:
        stockClean.append(int(cell)) #turn the string '4' into the integer 4
    except ValueError:
        if cell == 'N/A':
            stockClean.append(-1)
        else:
            stockClean.append(cell)
```

Comment: using your thought on single dl worked, if the site has multi tickers, then string is output and blows up like the the rest.

Comment: I am uisng some like the ans from link and above URL. Any help? Your method doesnt work for the problem stated a above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637553/python-url-download

Comment: Edited to reflect multiple stocks. Also added a section in case you want to do further cleaning up. Just replace the `stockClean = [-1...` with the second piece.

Comment: Now, i remember why I used .read vs. cvs.reader. Some fields have ",".

Comment: Shouldn't matter - they should be handled by the CSV reader none the less. I don't understand what you mean by "thanks, how would change to all variables sequentially?"

Comment: I solved most of it. without asking another Q. Last step using try/Except format.  IF XXX or YYY or ZZZ == 'N/A' , HOW do I call the except and pass on append, How do i do this.

Comment: csv reader splits 4,500 into 4, 500, two col where it should be one. PITA.

Comment: It depends on how the original CSV is setup and how the csv.reader is setup. Generally anyone generating CSVs will wrap them in quotes or escape the internal commas. If not it's a screwed up format.     I don't understand "HOW do I call the except and pass on the append" - what's troubling you? Edit your question if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

This list comprehension will loop through each item in `LL` and replace the string "N/A" with `-1`.

```
LL = [ ("text1",2,3,"N/A"), ("text2","N/A",5,6),("text3","N/A",5,"N/A") ]
LL = [tuple(x if x != "N/A" else -1 for x in i) for i in LL]
print LL
# [('text1', 2, 3, -1), ('text2', -1, 5, 6), ('text3', -1, 5, -1)]
```

If `N/A` is not a string then your code doesn't look like valid Python, edit your post and I will try to modify my answer accordingly.

Unfortunately, if you don't know where the `N/A` entries will be there is no way to replace them all without looping through all of your data.

**edit**: If `LL` is a string, then as others have said `replace` should do what you want, here is a complete example:

```
LL = '[ ("text1",2,3,N/A), ("text2",N/A,5,6),("text3",N/A,5,N/A) ]'
LL = LL.replace("N/A", "-1")
print LL
# [ ("text1",2,3,-1), ("text2",-1,5,6),("text3",-1,5,-1) ]
```

Comment: your code split every character, Some like [('"',), ('T',), ('E',), ('"',), (',',), ('N',), ............

Comment: You should edit your question to make it more clear that `LL` is a string, my method operates on `LL` as a list of tuples, which is what it looks like in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments on all the other answers, I think I see what's going on here:

LL is a string, meant to be a representation of a list of tuples, so something like this:

```
LL = '[ ("text1",2,3,N/A), ("text2",N/A,5,6),("text3",N/A,5,N/A) ]'
```

will create the kind of string user428862 is getting from this other system. We can replace the "N/A" values and convert the string to a usable list using this code:

```
import ast
LL_replaced = LL.replace('N/A', '-1')
LL_as_list = ast.literal_eval(LL_replaced)
```

Now `LL_as_list` is a list of tuples, with -1 wherever the "N/A"s were in the original string. Is this what you were after?

Comment: Could you add an example of how to declare `LL`? Your `LL =` line, with the N/A's, will not run in a Python interpreter. My version (wrapping the whole thing in quotes) will, but it sounds like that's not what you meant.

Comment: copy from above and paste.--my example, not yours.  then you'll see my problem Py think N/A is N divided by A, The data provider does not  text "N/A".

Comment: So after you download a file like that, what do you use to read it in to a Python variable?

Comment: use something like ans from link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637553/python-url-download

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand well your question, but if your data is downloaded as you say, you can probably assign

```
LL = [ ("text1",2,3,N/A), ("text2",N/A,5,6),("text3",N/A,5,N/A) ]
```

to a string:

`s = 'LL = [ ("text1",2,3,N/A), ("text2",N/A,5,6),("text3",N/A,5,N/A) ]'`

Now, `s.replace("N/A", "-1")` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NEW = [tuple(x if isinstance(x, (basestring, int, long, float)) else -1 for x in i) for i in LL]
```

It replace all elements with unknown types.

Comment: I found that LL is a string, not list. output is same @andrew