# Error checking in python

Tags: python, error-handling

After struggling with data download with ill tempered CSV fields. How could use try/Except format.

```
LL = [(XXX,YYY,ZZZ),] or [[XXX,YYY,ZZZ],]
```

if above, how do i do below?

```
try: 
   IF XXX or YYY or ZZZ or AAA == 'N/A',
   (dont process data...skip to except and pass)
except:
   pass
```

staeted here: 
[Remove/Replace Error from Tuple in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145939/remove-replace-error-from-tuple-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it's generally a bad idea to do a plain `except:`, as it will swallow exceptions that you need to know about.

```
LL = [("bad line",456,"N/A"),["good line", 123, 456],]

for line in LL:
    try: 
        if "N/A" in line:
            raise ValueError

        print line[0]

    except ValueError:
        print "skipped"
```

Comment: -1 Raising an exception only to trap it yourself in the same try block is ludicrous. Use if/else!

Comment: @John Machin, OP asked for an example using exceptions. Admittedly, it's not what I would have done if the actual code is really this trivial.

Comment: It's not what you should have done in non-trivial code either.

Comment: There are cases where raising and catching your own exception is a good technique. For example, if you have nested loops, or if there are other exceptions that might be raised. It can make the code simpler and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED

I suppose like that

```
try: 
   if "N/A" in [XXX,YYY,ZZZ,AAA]
       raise Exception()
except:
   pass
```

Comment: Assuming the original question was pseudocode and intended to check all fields against "N/A", this won't work. E.g. if XXX is "truthy", you'll throw the exception. (Same with YYY and ZZZ). These three aren't checked against "N/A".

Answer (score 1):

```
for data in LL:
   try:
      if "N/A" in data:
         continue
      else:
         x, y, z = data
         # Process data...
   except Exception:
      continue
```

Comment: I like this, but would change the conditional to `if 'N/A' in (x, y, z)` - it's cleaner and easier to read.